# Unable to install Eset Nod32

Tags: applications, security

Cannot get past the first step, which requires changing permissions on the Eset installer. Has anyone else installed Eset Nod32 for Linux home successfully on Elementary OS? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the file and click Properties. Under Permissions set **Owner** to Execute.

[image]

Comment: It worked! Thank you Storm!!